# To check linux firewall status without root privileges

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables

I'm writing a bash script which will check if the local firewall is up, and based on the status, perform some operation.
Ideally, within my script I would do:

```
su root --session-command="/etc/init.d/iptables status" ;
status=$? ;
```

So, if status = 1 it would mean that the firewall is down/not configured. And, if it's 0, that would mean that firewall is up.

But this requires for the user to enter root password during the script execution.

Is there some way of querying the iptables status without root privileges?

Sorry if this a newbie question. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use sudo rather than su root.  You can configure sudo to allow regular users access to this one command, rather than everything like they'd be able to do if you gave them the ability to "su root".

Answer (score -1):

Iptables is a kernel module, so looking for the process won't work.  For CentOS, at least, I found a decent way to do this without having to give special sudo permission:

```
[aaron@tg1 ~]$ /sbin/lsmod|grep ip_tables
ip_tables              17831  1 iptable_filter
[aaronr@tg1 ~]$
```

sbin isn't in the users' path normally, hence the absolute reference.

Reference: http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/IPTables

Comment: you can have the iptables kernel module loaded, that doesn't mean you have any firewall rules

Comment: You're right, that's true.  My use case is validating my Puppet config, which should have iptables unloaded.  If you're just trying to see if iptables is potentially blocking a port, though, this won't answer that.